# Limiting join results

Tags: sql, join

Apologies for the vague question and if this has been asked before, I had a hard time figuring out to articulate the question.

I have three tables; Lot and Salesorder, and OrderLot:

```
Lot      SKU   CreationDate
-------------------------
1000-a   1000  2017-04-12
1000-b   1000  2017-04-13
2000-a   2000  2017-04-12
2000-b   2000  2017-04-13

SalesorderID   Revenue
-----------------------------
1              $500
2              $250
3              $125


OrderLotID   SalesorderID Lot
------------------------------
1             1           1000-a
2             1           2000-a
3             2           1000-b
4             2           2000-b
5             3           1000-a
```

I'd like to do a join which gives me the total revenue generated given the creation date of the lots in the SalesOrder.

For example, I'd like to use the CreationDate of 2017-04-12 and get the result of $625 (Lots 1000-a and 2000-a were created on this date, and they were used to "fill" SalesorderIDs 1 and 3).  But the joins I'm currently using return two rows in the Salesorder 1 and the one row for Salesorder 3, and the result is $1125.

How do I limit the rows returned from the OrderLot so that only unique Salesorder revenue is counted?

Thanks,

jeff

edit.  current query is:

```
select sum(so.revenue)
from salesorder so
inner join orderlot ol on so.lot = ol.lot
inner join lot l on ol.lot = l.lot
where l.creationdate = '2017-04-12'
```

Comment: Your attempted query would be helpful to understand what needs to be corrected

Comment: So the Revenue is in total 500 for salesOrderID1 and you don't know what revenue exists by lot?

Comment: Correct.  The practical question is: how much Revenue did I generate given a production date.  Orders are "filled" with Lots.  So I need to get the revenue of all the orders filled with lots produced on a given date.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(s.Revenue)
FROM SalesOrder s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT SalesOrderID
    FROM Lot l
    INNER JOIN OrderLot ol on ol.Lot = l.Lot
    WHERE l.CreationDate = @CreationDate
) t ON T.SalesOrderID = s.SalesOrderID
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(s.Revenue)
FROM SalesOrder s
WHERE s.SalesOrderID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT SalesOrderID
    FROM Lot l
    INNER JOIN OrderLot ol on ol.Lot = l.Lot
    WHERE l.CreationDate = @CreationDate
)
```

I find the second option with the `IN()` condition slightly easier to understand, but I tend to lean towards `JOIN` when possible, as it tends to perform a little better in my experience and it's easier to adapt it for something more complicated. And as always, if the performance matters that much you should actually profile the query and look at the execution plan. The optimizer can always surprise you.

Comment: I thought about doing a sub-query using distinct, but for some reason that didn't seem right.  Not sure why I care (this is just a little tool I'm writing) but I thought there might be a way to avoid using "distinct."

Comment: You could always "GROUP BY" instead.